# Set the path of the symfony2 cache files during cache:clear

Tags: symfony, heroku

So my question is simple : Can we set the path of the symfony2 cache files during **cache:clear**, can we change it later or can we make it relative ? Or anything ?

Explanation :

I'm deploying a Symfony2 application on Heroku using a fork of a fork of [heroku-buildpack-php-tyler](https://github.com/iphoting/heroku-buildpack-php-tyler) : [heroku-buildpack-symfony2](https://github.com/Azer-/heroku-buildpack-symfony2).

On deployment the platform receives a **git push** to a random temporary location say */tmpXXXX/* for compilation/installation/etc.

After compilation it stores the content of */tmpXXXX/* like a 'zip install' of the app to easily to deploy it on other instances. Then the app gets deployed to the */app/* dir of new instances on startup.

**Problem is**, if we run a **cache:clear** before the end of the compilation, the path of the cache files are dumped from the */tmpXXXX/* location... Breaking everything.

So the turnaround is to warmup the cache during startup, and it works, but it often takes more than 60 seconds, and on heroku if your app boots in more than 60 second, [it gets rebooted](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h20-app-boot-timeout) and you get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my own question as I made a pr for it on the CCH/Heroku buildpack

A simple `sed` did the trick as in this [file](https://github.com/CHH/heroku-buildpack-php/blob/a7e25a0be819607d758516b533d46b31e386b037/frameworks/symfony2#L45).

code looks like this :

```
    find $CACHE_DIR/app/cache/prod -type f -exec sed -i "s@$CACHE_DIR@$APP_DIR@g" {} \; | indent
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [custom Symfony environment called "deploy"](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/environments.html) for your deployment and then [override the different cache folders](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/override_dir_structure.html).

Once you have your new environment (named "deploy" in the example below), you could override the method `getCacheDir` of the class `app/AppKernel.php` to something like this

```
public function getCacheDir()
{
    if ($this->environment === "deploy") {
        return '/the/path/to/your/symfony/cache/'.$this->environment;
    } else {
        return $this->rootDir.'/cache/'.$this->environment;
    }
}
```

Make sure the environment is only accessible locally by trusted users.

Comment: Good idea ! But thad would also mean that my cache files would be dumped to  /app/app/cache/ and that I'd have to copy them back to my local dir before the end of the container's compilation.
I'll think about it.

Answer (score 0):

There are discussions & proper solutions for this happening here...

https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/issues/64

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/10999

And a new buildpack with fix (I will try it now)

https://github.com/CHH/heroku-buildpack-php/pull/67

Comment: Hey there, yup, the fix I made is still there !